# How to set directoryMode Permissions for folder in assembly descriptor?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

I cant seem to change the output directory permissions in my assembly descriptor. It seems to be ignored entirely. The file permissions however are set correctly. I am using Maven 3.

```
<fileSet>
    <directory>src/main/conf</directory>
    <fileMode>0644</fileMode>
    <directoryMode>0755/directoryMode>
    <outputDirectory>conf</outputDirectory>
</fileSet>
```

The directories still appear as 775.

```
drwxrwxr-x
```

Is this a known bug? I even tried defining a fileset separately excluding all files and just specifying the output directory but to no avail.

Any tips or workarounds appreciated.

Comment: I just tested it on maven 2 and it works just fine.

Comment: hmm interesting. thanks for the comment. Any attempt on maven 3?

Comment: Sorry, have no time to check this with maven 3.

Comment: Could you let me know which assembly plugin version you used please Andrew. Much appreciated if you can. I tried with 2.2.1 and it doesn't work.

Comment: It's actually 2.2.1. Why don't you try with maven 2 and see if it works?

Comment: What kind of artifact are you building?  What method are you using to unpack it later?

Comment: The most important question is: Which version of the maven-assembly-plugin are you using? Have you defined the version yourself or just getting this via the super pom?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to have been a bug ([MASSEMBLY-621](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MASSEMBLY-621)) with the assembly plugin. This bug was fixed in version 2.4. I too was facing this problem, upgrading the plugin from 2.3 to 2.4 resolved this issue (using Maven 2.2.1, did not test Maven 3).

Other related bugs:

- [MASSEMBLY-422](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MASSEMBLY-422)

Comment: With 2.2-beta-5 it also fails. With 2.4.x it works in Maven 3